# I need a responsive HTML Structure as an iframe

Tags: html, iframe, responsive-design

I built an HTML page to display it as an iframe and on desktop everything works fine. Now I would like to make it responsive and transform the layout of the content via media queries. I don't know what is going on but the HTML element keeps a width of 960px.
I used Atom and it gave me a HTML structure that I used for a simple test.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Viewport Test</title>
        <style media="screen">
            body {
                text-align: center;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <span>TEST</span>
    </body>
</html>
```

I use the dev tools of Chrome to test the responsive layout and I set the width of the window to 360px but the HTML document keeps at 960px.
I cant understand what's going on here.
Please help me and thank you.

Comment: i hope it will be use full for you.
https://stackoverflow.com/q/32429655/12133934

Comment: If you have CORS access you can use `contentWindow.document` to get the iframe content document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is related anywhere to your question. Refer this once if it helps.

Discussed issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17838607/making-an-iframe-responsive).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I needed to beet me trough the posts but I found what I needed^^
The right answer for my Problem is: I or Atom forgot that dam <meta> Tag in the Head
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">

Now my html structure is ready for my responsive iframe.
Thanks alot again @Revanth

Comment: Good that you got the error cleared :) Have a good one mate @user11631482

Answer (score 0):

thx @sao for spending your time to editing my post at first.
But does realy noone had any thoughts in this Case?